# modal window "loading" not loading in SCALD

Tags: ajax, javascript, scald

I'm working on a site using SCALD – and for some reason the modal media upload window does not work anymore. It's stuck with the status "loading…" but not going anywhere.

I first had it running like a charm – then I 'just' wanted to add multi-language support to the website adding i18n… Then when I checked again on SCALD this is all I get:

[image]

**Firebug console** is showing the following two messages:

`Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help xhr.spec.whatwg.org ...A.onload=A.onreadystatechange=null;r&&A.parentNode&&r.removeChild(A)}}}r.inse‌​rtB…" (jquery.js?v=1.4.4 line 139)`

and

`uncaught exception: The editor instance "edit-body-und-0-value" is already attached to the provided element.`

[image]

**Firebug network:** "POST ajax 200 OK"

So for what I can see from other modules ajax is up and running. Checking on other forum questions here on drupal-stackexange concerning modal window problems didn't help yet – so I just hope somebody has some pointers that would direct me in some direction… ThankYou!

–EDIT-
manual upload (atom/add/image) works and also using the SCALD library incl. drag'n'drop works fine. Just opening the modal dialogue either through "add" or "edit" form the SCALD sidebar does not load.

PS: not using the jQuery update module

Comment: Check the "Network" tab after you fire the ajax command (have it open before you do that). It should show you the ajax HTTP request and the response code it receives. From there you can start debugging, if it's 500 error, should be in the logs (php/drupal watchdog).

Comment: The network tab does'n show anything – the only entry i get is the 200ok on reload. But when opening the modal window no new entry is generated. So I guess the ajax isn't fired at all?! …strange…

Comment: ps: the console does however show these two messages: "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/
...A.onload=A.onreadystatechange=null;r&&A.parentNode&&r.removeChild(A)}}}r.insertB…" (jquery.js?v=1.4.4 line 139)

Comment: --and--
"uncaught exception: The editor instance "edit-body-und-0-value" is already attached to the provided element."

Comment: Well that directly contradicts what you wrote on your original question: "And firebug doesn't show any errors in the console". Please update the question.

Comment: yup - updated… i either first didn't see these two messages (?!) or they weren't there?! …strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it: the problem was that after going through the SCALD installation process the CKEditor was activated and the plugins declared in two locations:

1. under WYSIWYG Profiles
2. under CKEditor Profiles

This also corresponds with the error message I had in FF console:

```
uncaught exception: The editor instance "edit-body-und-0-value" is already attached to the provided element.
```

I simply deleted the WYSIWYG Profile and the problem was gone – modal window loading as it should. The detailled documentation of the process finding the error can be found over here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2454845#comment-9749453